# Using Jquery inside of Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I'm trying to pass a string from javascript to a razor ActionLink

`string filtering =$("#Hello").val();`

`@Html.ActionLink(Name, ControllerName, new { sort = columm, order = orderby, filters = filtering })`

but I'm not able to access to this variable, I already try `@:filtering` or `"@filtering"` but doesn't work anyway,

How can I pass the variable to the controller?

Comment: You can't do it with `Html.ActionLink`. Razor runs on the server side while your javascript runs inside your browser... You will need AJAX to send back data to your server.

Comment: are you want to access filter value to controller action?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send or post the data to Controller's Action then you may try this...

```
 <input type="submit" id="btnFilter" value="Filter" name="btnFilter" />

$('#btnFilter').click(function () {

        var sort = sortValue;
        var order = orderValue;
        var filter= filterValue;

   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action(ActionName, ControllerName)',
            data:'{"sort":"' + sort+ '","order":"' + order+ '","filter":"' + filter+ '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {


            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });

});
```

then.... in controller action

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string sort ,string order , string filter)
{
    // do Something here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add the parameter to the URL yourself manually using jQuery to assign the `href` attribute of the anchor tag.

First, let's take off the filter parameter off your `ActionLink` and give it an ID (so we can reference it in jQUery):

```
@Html.ActionLink(Name, Controller, new { sort = columm, order = orderby }, new { id = "myLink" })
```

Then do the following jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var newLink = $("#myLink").attr("href") + "?filter= " + $("#Hello").val();
    $("#myLink").attr("href", newLink); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the way that I could do it was passing the Url to the controller
`window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/Name/Controller/" + "?sort=sort" + "&order=order" + "&page=page" + "&filters=" + filter;`